# Windows will not open processes

Tags: windows-7, performance, freeze, defragment, safe-mode

I recently I come upon an unexplainable issue concerning my Windows 7 partition. When I woke up Thursday morning and logged into Windows, I discovered that it was acting really slow. It didn't take that long to boot, but nothing would happen when I opened a program. It would act like it would open, then nothing would appear and the system would freeze. I could open WordPad and Windows Explorer, albeit it took a while, but I couldn't open Firefox or Skype. When I tried to load Windows Media Player, it would freeze whenever I clicked in the window. This is really odd because it was working fine the night before. My Fedora 20 partition is working just fine, and it also works fine on Safe Mode (and With Networking). I restarted many times, but it acts the same each time. I even did a system restore to Tuesday, but it acts the same. My hard drive has been quite full recently, so I moved more stuff off to see if that would help. No change.

I have loaded Task Manager to see if any programs are taking up a lot of space. I have very little CPU and memory usage, less than usual. I discovered that when I try to open a program, like Steam, it will be at 100KB usage and will not move, even if I change the priority. So it seems that most program I open will not open all the way.

I discovered that the defragmenter runs on 1:00 AM on Wednesdays. This Wednesday is one of the few times I have ever stayed up that late with my computer on, so I assume it finally got to run. Could this be what caused it? If not, what are some other options I can take?

Comment: Sounds like disk problems to me.  Check your event logs for disk/controller related errors.  Scan your file system/disks (use chkdsk).

Comment: Is the disk defragment still running?

Comment: The disk defragment isn't running. I don't remember it ever running, but it must have been in the background. I chkdsk and it fixed some bad sectors. That must have been all it needed. It's fine now.